# Not able to find out the java application url deployed through helm on a local kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

Have deployed an application successfully using helm chart but I am unable to understand which url should I use to access it ..Here is the Nodeport service created by Helm for this web app :

```
kubectl get svc
NAME                      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
demo-springboot-demoweb   NodePort   10.101.86.143   <none>        8080:31384/TCP   11m
xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx5 charts % kubectl describe svc
Name:                     demo-springboot-demoweb
Namespace:                springboot-demoweb
Labels:                   app=springboot-demoweb
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          chart=springboot-demoweb-0.1.0
                          heritage=Helm
                          release=demo
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: demo
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: springboot-demoweb
Selector:                 app=springboot-demoweb,release=demo
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.101.86.143
IPs:                      10.101.86.143
Port:                     nginx  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 nginx  31384/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.15:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: What does ```kubectl get route``` return?

Comment: @AddeusExMachina kubectl get route          
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "route"

Comment: Use the public IP of one of the worker nodes, with port 31384

Comment: Try chaning *route* to *routes*, that is, run: ```kubectl get routes```

Comment: @BurakSerdar Since it is a single node Minikube cluster , I am getting connection refused while using its ip , doing curl within the same session

Comment: @AddeusExMachina still the same error

Comment: Is your application listening on port 8080 of that container?

Answer (score 1):

You have deployed an application that is exposed using a Service of kind NodePort.

That means that all nodes of the cluster expose the application on the same port - the port number is coordinated.

So you need the ip of one of the nodes to access the cluster.
You can use `kubectl get nodes -o wide` to get the nodes and IP addresses. If it is a local cluster it will be shown as `INTERNAL IP`.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   155m   v1.23.3   192.168.49.2   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS   5.15.0-37-generic   docker://20.10.12
```

Use one of the IPs together with your NodePort which is `31384`. In my example it would be: http://192.168.49.2:31384

Comment: Even I have  the same internal IP  but it still fails with connection refused error after sometime.

Comment: Verify that the app is running `kubectl get pods -n springboot-demoweb` and the service has appropriate endpoints assigned. `kubectl get endpoints -l app=springboot-demoweb -n springboot-demoweb --show-labels`

Comment: Do not use the internal port, use the external node port - it is 31384 in your example, not 8080

Comment: 'NAME                      ENDPOINTS          AGE   LABELS
demo-springboot-demoweb   172.17.0.15:8080   78m   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app=springboot-demoweb,chart=springboot-demoweb-0.1.0,heritage=Helm,release=demo'

Comment: Looks fine, if it is still not working, what is the curl command you are using? Make sure there is no firewall preventing the access.

Comment: curl http://192.168.49.2:31384 , is it okay ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246100/discussion-between-rohit-and-thomas).